# How to avoid explicitly declaring ivars in Mac app releases?

Tags: cocoa, ivar

I know that since iOS 4.0 it's not necessary to explicitly declare ivars. I just use `@synthesize myVar = _myVar;` This suits me fine since it's less typing, although I don't really know why or which setting this comes from. I was trying to do the same in my Mac app. It worked while building in debug mode, however, once I switched to making an archive, the compiler started complaining. Is there a way to suppress this?

Comment: Declaring ivars is too much typing?  Hmmm...

Comment: haha Not that I can't do it but after I've gone through the trouble of removing them all.. I'm clutter-phobic yes :)

Comment: The problem is you'll go back to the code and it won't be *quite* so obviousl how it works when there are no member variables.  I wouldn't say that member variables are clutter.  Anyway, I don't know the answer to your question :)

Comment: This should work the same on Mac OS as on iOS as long as you're compiling for the "modern" ObjC runtime -- that is, for Intel 64-bit. (And in this day and age, there's little point to compiling for 32-bit Intel or PPC... indeed, 64-bit is the default for new Xcode projects.) Either your build settings are set up wrong or the error you're seeing is unrelated. What error are you seeing?

Comment: @rickster Thank you for your comment. It did turn out that I had outdated settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synthesizing ivars only works for 64-bit applications, since it requires new runtime features only found in the "new" runtime (and in the iOS one). It is likely that you're compiling your debug version for your system (which will be 64 bit), yet creating a universal 32/64 bit binary for the archive target. The solution would be to change the release config to 64-bit-only.

Comment: That was it! I did have a universal 32/64 in my settings. Thank you.